# Why doesn't this variable assignment work when using tee?

Tags: shell-script, tee

Consider:

```
$ FILE_NAME=`(cat somefile | head -1)` | tee -a dump.txt
$ echo $FILE_NAME

$
```

1. Now, why doesn't the output of `(cat somefile | head -1)` reach the standard input of tee ..?
2. If the output reached tee, then it could copy it to dump.txt file and the standard output.
3. Also the variable `$FILE_NAME` does not receive the value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably meant to write

```
FILE_NAME=`(cat somefile | head -1) | tee -a dump.txt`
echo $FILE_NAME
```

(or `head -1 somefile` to get rid of the cat)

The pipe outside ` is more of a logic error. You'd expect it to be a syntax error but that's not how Bash works, it just doesn't give the expected result.

Also compare without the variable assignment:

```
$ echo hello > somefile
$ `(cat somefile | head -1)` | tee -a dump.txt
bash: hello: command not found
```

The first line of somefile is not echoed to stdout, but interpreted as a command instead. Since the command can't be executed, tee doesn't get output, and isn't really executed either as there is no pipe to make.